# UserWarning: Update your `Model` call to the Keras 2 API: `Model(inputs=Tensor("in..., outputs=Tensor("co...)`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to train an unet model and my main program is smth like this:

```
data_gen_args = dict(rotation_range=0.2,
                width_shift_range=0.05,
                height_shift_range=0.05,
                shear_range=0.05,
                zoom_range=0.05,
                horizontal_flip=True,
                fill_mode='nearest')
myGene=trainGenerator(2,'PATH','org','png',data_gen_args,save_to_dir = None)
model = unet()
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('unet_membrane.hdf5', monitor='loss',verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
model.fit_generator(myGene,steps_per_epoch=100,epochs=10, callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
```

When it starts learning gives an error like:

> UserWarning: Update your `Model` call to the Keras 2 API: `Model(inputs=Tensor("in..., outputs=Tensor("co...)`
>     model = Model(input = inputs, output = conv10)

I understand that it is because my model.py is local thats why I wanted to update it and wasn't able to do. Could you please tell me how I can do it ?

One more thing my code is showing 70-75% accuracy I want to to improve my code at least 90% for current program what I should add for better results?

Thanks!!

Comment: That is not an error, its just a warning, it does not affect anything.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your model is created using `Keras 1` [syntax](http://faroit.com/keras-docs/1.2.2/models/model/):

```
model = Model(input=my_input, output=my_output)
```

instead of `Keras 2` [syntax](https://keras.io/models/model/):

```
model = Model(inputs=my_input, outputs=my_output)
```

Just change that and it won't complain.

Regarding your accuracy, we do not know how you create your model and what your data is, what you are trying to solve. So that just depends on the type of task and for you to explore.